# Vue js watch object with debounce

Tags: vuejs2

I have data object `localFilter` inside component  having 3 props and what i need is to watch for any props get changed inside this object   and debounce in 1 second.
If i had one property the code below works, but what's the best way when i need whole object watcher with debounce?

```
export default {
  name: "my-search",
  data: () => ({
    localFilter: null
  }),
  props: {
    value: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },    
  watch: {
    'localFilter.searchText': _.debounce(function() {
      console.log(this.localFilter);
      this.$emit("input", Object.assign({}, this.localFilter));
    }, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deep watch an object:

```
watch: {
    // any prop or data or $props or $data
    $props: {
        deep: true,
        handler: _.debounce( /*...*/)
    },
}
```